# How to restrict the rotation of an object when using transform.Rotate()?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to limit the rotation of an object on the **x-axis**.
The rotation is performed as follows:

```
float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
transform.Rotate(moveVertical * rotationRate * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
```

I tried to do it like this:

```
   if( transform.rotation.x > -89f && tranform.rotation.x < 89f) 
{
   transform.Rotate(moveVertical * rotationRate * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0); 
}
```

But then Unity breaks, and PlayMode doesn't turn on at all...
I have to restart the program through the task Manager.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the reason your Unity doesn't play is because you have a mistake in your code and "transform" is spelled wrong in your if statement, so this should fix that:

```
if(transform.rotation.x > -89f && transform.rotation.x < 89f) 
{
   transform.Rotate(moveVertical * rotationRate * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0); 
}
```

If that isn't the case please let us know what error you are getting when trying to run Unity.

Also with your code you aren't limiting the rotation about the x-axis between -89 and 89 as you are checking the wrong variable. `rotation.x` refers to the x value of the quaternion which is likely not what you are looking for. To check the amount that an objected is rotate by you should instead use:

```
if(transform.eulerAngles.x > -89f && transform.eulerAngles.x < 89f) 
{
   transform.Rotate(moveVertical * rotationRate * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0); 
}
```